# Using std::enable_if on template function return type to exploit SFINAE - compilation error

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

The following code

```
#include <type_traits>

struct CByteArray {};
struct HLVariant {
    HLVariant() {}
    HLVariant(const HLVariant&) {}
    HLVariant(const CByteArray&) {}

    };

template <typename T>
inline typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pod<T>::value, CByteArray>::type serialize(const T& value)
{
    return serialize(HLVariant(value));
}

template <typename T>
inline typename std::enable_if<std::is_pod<T>::value, CByteArray>::type serialize(const T& value)
{
    return CByteArray();
}

template <>
inline CByteArray serialize(const HLVariant& value)
{
    return CByteArray();
}

int main()
{
    serialize(0);
    serialize(CByteArray());
    serialize(HLVariant());

    return 0;
}
```

triggers a compilation error `C2794: 'type' : is not a member of any direct or indirect base class of 'std::enable_if<false,CByteArray>'` in MSVC 2013. It does, however, work in ideone: [enter link description here](http://ideone.com/WTaWpD)

What's the mistake here?

The error is the same in MSVC 2010, 2012 and 2013.

Comment: I would bet on the error being "MSVC 2013" :)

Comment: @Pradhan: if you imply that MS compiler is somehow inferior to GCC, then you couldn't be further from truth.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe In C++ language compliance?  The MS compiler is miles behind.  It has other advantages, but don't kid yourself about C++ language compliance.  What update of MSVC 2013?

Comment: works fine in VS14 CTP

Comment: @Yakk: Riiight, it's not C++14-compliant yet. Anyway, can we get back to the topic please?

Comment: No, it isn't C++11 compliant.  It would be a stretch to say it is C++03 compliant.  So, what update of MSVC2013 are you using? (GM?  U1?  U2?  U3? -- they differ) What line in particular does the error occur on?   Can you eliminate the code that doesn't prevent the error -- it should occur with only 1 overload of `serialize`, which would make it easier to work out what is going wrong.  If you delete the `serialize` that do not have the error on it, will it still generate the error?  If so, edit your post with the simpler code.

Comment: @Yakk: It occurs with MSVC 2010, 2012 and 2013 so it shouldn't matter which update I have (Update 3, if you still think it's relevant). I think there's nothing I could eliminate without removing relevant code. According to the error message, error occurs at line 27.

Comment: @Yakk: fair enough, let me try. I'm still not sure that's an equivalent transformation, though, since SFINAE will no longer be used for template resolution.

Comment: SFINAE happens before overloads are picked by the standard.  Looking below, the `template<>` may be involved in the problem, which might be a side effect of how MSVC does full specialization.  Which line is line 27?

Comment: @Yakk: line 27 is the closing brace of `template <> CByteArray serialize(const HLVariant& value)` body. Whatever that's supposed to mean.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it.  MSVC is treating that as a full specialization of ... both? ... of the templates above, and for some reason doing substitution back into the original, and getting an error that it treats as hard.  As a general rule, don't specialize template functions, function template specialization is done poorly.

Comment: @Yakk: I've experimented with it, and I can say two things for sure: 1. the error occurs during any compilation of the template code, not just during instantiation. I. e. if I remove all `serialize` calls the error remains.

Comment: @Yakk:  2. The compiler attempts to compile (or maybe just parse, I don't know)  every specialization and every base non-specialized version, it doesn't understand that I'm trying to hide them. In other words: when the compiler encounters `<> serialize (const int&)` specialization, it then attempts to substitute `int` into both base versions of the template, and since one of them is always hidden - compilation of 1 of the bae functions will always fail regarldess of the type once the compiler encounters `enable_if<false, T>`. Compiler bug?

Comment: It is trying to figure out which template function your specialization is a specialization of is my guess, and doing so via substitution, and generating hard errors.  Don't specialize function templates, it is almost always a bad idea, even if there wasn't a MSVC bug here.

Comment: @Yakk: how so? Why a bad idea, I mean? Will it help if I turn my free function templates into class member function templates? Or class templates?

Comment: Because specialization reacts with overloads strangely, and often does not do what you think it should do.  Specialize classes, overload functions.

Comment: @Yakk: In this case I need a template, so overloading is out of the question. So, you're saying I should enclose the `serialize` function into a class template, and specialize that template? What about specializing a template method of a non-template class?

Comment: You are already using overloads -- you have two template functions that overload each other.  They are NOT specializations of each other.  If you think you need a single template function, you have already failed at your task.  Template functions can overload each other fine, and non-template functions can participate in overload resolution with them (with care).

Comment: @Yakk: How is it overloading, if only 1 of the 2 function variants can even be compiled? _And_ they have exactly the same signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks ok to me, but I can fix it by removing the `template<>` from the final overload of `serialize`. No need to make it a full specialisation when a normal overload will do!

EDIT: What else works is providing a template specialisation which matches only `HLVariant` (and further restricting the other specialisations to no longer match `HLVariant`, to avoid ambiguity).

This should do it:

http://ideone.com/0UGkcn

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct CByteArray {};
struct NonPod {public: int a; private: int b;};
struct HLVariant {
    HLVariant() {}
    HLVariant(const HLVariant&) {}
    HLVariant(const CByteArray&) {}
    HLVariant(const NonPod&) {}
};

template <typename T>
inline typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, HLVariant>::value && !std::is_pod<T>::value, CByteArray>::type serialize(const T& value)
{
    std::cout << "serialize non-pod variant\n";
    return CByteArray();
}

template <typename T>
inline typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, HLVariant>::value && !std::is_pod<T>::value, CByteArray>::type serialize(const T& value)
{
    std::cout << "serialize non-pod non-variant\n";
    return serialize(HLVariant(value));
}

template <typename T>
inline typename std::enable_if<std::is_pod<T>::value, CByteArray>::type serialize(const T& value)
{
    std::cout << "serialize pod\n";
    return CByteArray();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "int:\n";
    serialize(0);
    std::cout << "CByteArray:\n";
    serialize(CByteArray());
    std::cout << "HLVariant:\n";
    serialize(HLVariant());
    std::cout << "NonPod:\n";
    serialize(NonPod());
}
```

Comment: I see what you did there... Problem is, in my actual code such an overload will incur a whole bunch of errors, since non-template overloads take precedence (IIRC), and `HLvariant` can be constructed from like 50 different types through non-explicit constructors. In other words, wrong versions of `serialize` will get called.

Comment: The user defined conversion should be a less-good match than a template exact match?

Comment: Ok, sounds like you want a template specialisation which matches only `HLVariant` (and to prevent the other specialisations matching `HLVariant` to avoid ambiguity). I'll update...

Comment: @BenHymers: yes, that is exactly correct. And I will add more specializations in future.

Comment: So specialization doesn't work, but hiding with `enable_if` still does? I've run a brief check - it does compile in MSVC.

Comment: Yes, I believe your original code should be accepted, and that it fails to compile in MSVC is a bug; this is just a workaround, which is sadly quite cumbersome...